# Wordpress behind Apache reverse proxy redirect loop only on home page

Tags: wordpress, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have a Wordpress server behind an Apache2 reverse Proxy. I've managed to make all pages work with custom permalinks, but when trying to access the home page (https://www.example.com) I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Pages like https://www.example.com/contact work just fine.

Here is my **.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my Apache2 reverse proxy entries

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerName www.example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   SSLProxyEngine On
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
   SSLProxyVerify none
   SSLCertificateFile       /etc/certs/example.com/fullchain1.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/certs/example.com/privkey1.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/certs/example.com/chain1.pem
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"


   ProxyPass / https://x.x.x.x/ nocanon
   ProxyPassReverse / https://x.x.x.x/
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: WP Site name]

Any idea what could be causing the issue?

I've tried countless changed in htaccess and on the proxy and the best result I got is everything working but the home page.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with the same issue, I solved it by adding this to the Apache reverse proxy:

```
   ProxyPreserveHost On
```